# Visualsvn - Tortoise svn repo browser doesn't connect to new url after relocate

Tags: svn, browser, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, repository

I am trying the Enterprise version of Visual SVN server to use Integrated Windows auth. I enabled Integrated Windows auth, checked the Use SSL box, and then did a relocate on my working copy (checked externals too). It works fine from the right click menu.

The regular directories also work in the repo browser; however, when I click on the externals folder in the repo browser it displays the message "Unable to connection to a repository URL" and gives me the old non-SSL url I was using. I believe this is because I need to update Visual SVN to point at the new url for externals. I am trying to find how to do this, but so far I haven't found anything helpful on Google.

When I open Visual SVN and copy the url of the externals folder it is correct. I can access the externals directory from my machine in Tortoise Repo Browser fine if If I type the URL in manually (this only shows the externals directory though).

My question is, where/how do I update Visual Svn server to point at the new URL for the externals?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. I found where you update it in the repo browser. This takes affect server side.